# Change AppCompatActivity into Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app use voice recognition, you type on a button it recognize the word and put it on TextView. It has an activity and I want to change it on fragment but I faced with a few problems:

My original code works good and looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button recognizeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    recognizeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View context) {
    final DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    final Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale("en");
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String str="";
        for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
            str+= results.get(i);
        }
        if (str.equals("five")) {
            speechText.setText(str);
        }else{
            speechText.setText("It's not: " + str);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I change it on Fragment and it's crashes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, container, false);
    final DisplayMetrics dm = container.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    final Configuration conf = container.getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale("en");
    container.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Button recognizeButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    recognizeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

//    @Override
//    public void setContentView(View context) {
//        final DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
//        final Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
//        conf.locale = new Locale("en");
//        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
//    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        TextView speechText = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvPage);
        String str="";
        for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
            str+= results.get(i);
        }
        if (str.equals("five")) {
            speechText.setText(str);
        }else{
            speechText.setText("It's not: " + str);
        }
    }
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:name="htgroup.welcome.voiceapp.MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="recognize"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp" />
</LinearLayout>


Log:   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: htgroup.welcome.voiceapp, PID: 1699
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{htgroup.welcome.voiceapp/htgroup.welcome.voiceapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: htgroup.welcome.voiceapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: htgroup.welcome.voiceapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: `Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment` means problem is with xml please show xml file

Answer (score 1):

Probably :

```
   <fragment
    android:name="htgroup.welcome.voiceapp.MainActivity" //<<
    ....
    />
```

lines causing issue.

fragment `android:name` attribute always contains name of Fragment with full package name instead of Activity name in which Fragment is add.

Change `android:name` as to get it work:

```
    <fragment
      android:name="htgroup.welcome.voiceapp.ButtonFragment"
    ....
    />
```

Considering `ButtonFragment` class is inside `htgroup.welcome.voiceapp` package

Comment: Thanks for the answer(+1 to your karma), but it still crashes: `Log: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: htgroup.welcome.voiceapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity `. Maybe that's because in `onActivityResult` I used `Activity.RESULT_OK`, if so without Activity it's `RESULT_OK` become red.

Comment: @Nikolai: at which line getting issue? please share latest logs with question

Comment: @Nikolai: you have two files name same `MainActivity` how?

Comment: @Nikolai: Use different names for both files

Comment: Thanks A LOT for attantion to my post! I found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

1.In onCreate I commented this rows (see below)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, container, false);
//        final DisplayMetrics dm = container.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
//        final Configuration conf = container.getResources().getConfiguration();
//        conf.locale = new Locale("en");
//        container.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Button recognizeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        recognizeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }
```

2. I created new class Button

   ```
   public class Button extends FragmentActivity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
   ```

   }
3. In Manifest I changed .MainActivity to .Button